# Parsing a table on webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying get a table from the website [SGX](https://www2.sgx.com/securities/securities-prices?code=all).

The page is saved to local drive and I am using BeautifulSoup to parse it:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(pages), "lxml")
soup.prettify()

list_0 = soup.find_all('table')[0]
print list_0
```

What it returned, is not the first row on the page:

```
[<tr><td>Zhongmin Baihui</td><td>5SR</td><td class="nowrap">09:44 AM</td><td class="nowrap">09:49 AM</td><td>0.615</td><td>0.675</td><td>0.555</td></tr>]
```

What's the right way to retrieve this table?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if you have some class or id in your table you can filter by class or id `soup.findAll('table', {'class': 'some_class', 'id': 'some_id'})`

Comment: i found that table is not in table tag but in div `soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'table-container'})[0]` this will get you the table you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data are being fetched after page loads using AJAX request, by inspecting the page you can find the API URL (the Url below), and then you can use something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

response = requests.get('https://api.sgx.com/securities/v1.1?excludetypes=bonds&params=nc%2Cadjusted-vwap%2Cb%2Cbv%2Cp%2Cc%2Cchange_vs_pc%2Cchange_vs_pc_percentage%2Ccx%2Ccn%2Cdp%2Cdpc%2Cdu%2Ced%2Cfn%2Ch%2Ciiv%2Ciopv%2Clt%2Cl%2Co%2Cp_%2Cpv%2Cptd%2Cs%2Csv%2Ctrading_time%2Cv_%2Cv%2Cvl%2Cvwap%2Cvwap-currency')
data = json.loads(response.content)["data"]["prices"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

If your requirement are complex and your crawling done in regular basis I recommend using scrapy.